# How to partman/preseed with GPT

Tags: partitioning, gpt, preseed

I need to make partitions of a server which has a 3TB HDD. This partitions must be done using preseed file(automatic).

I've been searching but I can't clearly understand how `partman` works in the preseed file.

For example:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string          \
  standard ::                                  \ 
    1000 10000 1000000000 xfs                  \
    $primary{}                                 \
    method{format}                             \
    format{}                                   \
    use_filesystem{}                           \
    filesystem{xfs}                            \
    label{root}                                \
    mountpoint{/}                              \
```

I don't understand the `100 10000 1000000000` line, what do those numbers mean?

What other `method`s are, and why are they doing `format` as a `method`?

Why is it declared another `format{}`?

Why do you have to specify to `use_filesystem`? When should you, like, not use a filesystem?

How can I define I want to use `ext4` filesystem with `GPT` partitioning?

Sorry if I'm asking too much... Than you all.

Answer (score 1):

Great documentation of what the various options mean (and also a somewhat insanely clever approach around scripting the expert-recipe) https://www.claudioborges.org/?p=733

Example implementing gpt https://gist.github.com/robertstarmer/7332658

I feel your pain WRT preseed and partman.

Comment: Good start, but we recommend here to summarize the main points of the documents you refer to..That will help future readers in case the link is broken in the future.